# CRM case resolution in 2016

Tags: dynamics-crm-2016

While resolving the case if we use prmContext.getEventArgs().preventDefault(); to stop the case getting resolved , it keeps processing and nothing happens.

Has somebody also faced this issue.

Comment: Are you using this code https://crmbusiness.wordpress.com/2012/03/14/crm-2011-adding-validation-to-the-resolve-case-button/ ? I'd guess the Turbo Form is interfering.

Comment: I am doing the same but the requirement is different and in crm 2016 there is no point in checking the getSaveMode() as it returns same value for both resolve case and save. I have some html grid and I am checking if at least one is not selected stop the resolution of case.

Answer (score 0):

I never had to do this customization in particular, but I'd put the logic in a plugin firing on `Create` of `IncidentResolution` entity (post-operation so you can have the Images available).

Throw there and the resolution flow should be rolled back.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I am doing it via Javascript only.